# Android считать Xml данные из .aspx

Tags: android, xml

Добрый день, для одного моего проекта необходим Xml файл, дело было бы простым, да вот только он находится на .aspx странице, вопрос в том, как его от туда вытащить, если это вообще возможно. Была идея - скачать страницу и оттуда уже локально считать Xml, но как это реализовать я к сожалению тоже не придумал. Если есть решение я был бы рад примеру либо источнику !

Comment: Как это на aspx странице?

Comment: это веб страница сайта, на которой помимо нужного  XML ничего нет